# What transaction IsolationLevel should I use?

Tags: c#, wcf

I am writing a WCF web service which allows to register new users in system. So I have the following operation contract:

```
 [ServiceContract]
 public interface ISecurityService
 {
     /// <summary>
     /// Register new user in system, if no exceptions were thrown 
     /// user was registered successfully
     /// </summary>
     [OperationContract]
     [FaultContract(typeof(SecurityFaultException))]
     void Register(string userName, string password);
 }
```

The idea is simple how to synchronize `Register` method invocation to prevent registration of two users with the same names?

I thought about using `IsolationLevel.Serializable` but I'm not sure about this solution. Can somebody give me a good advice or share some good practice about WCF services synchronization.

UPDATED:
I save users in a database.

Comment: Why do you want to serialise register calls? (This is to understand the nature of the need for transaction isolation.)

Comment: where are you storing the registered users? In memory or in a database?

Comment: I think it should be enough when UserName has a Unique constraint in the Db. IsolationLevel should not be relevant for Insert.

Comment: I store users in database and when i spoke about transaction isolation level i meant database access. Thanks for advices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you save users in db it's enough to use default Isolationlevel(ReadCommited) an just put a unique constraint or primary key in UserName column that prevent duplicate value.